# Omnet++ Castalia Energy Consumption

Tags: omnet++

I did this .ini file to try to simulate the amount of energy consumed in a Linear WSN that is placed in a railway , but the energy consumption is not what I expected and i dont understand, does someone know what is happening?

I want Node 0 to be the cordinatoor and Node 9 to be the node able to sense and to forward the data to Node 0

the code :

```
[General]

include ../Parameters/Castalia.ini

repeat = 2

sim-time-limit = 7000s

SN.numNodes = 10


SN.node[1].xCoor = 10
SN.node[2].xCoor = 20
SN.node[3].xCoor = 30
SN.node[4].xCoor = 40
SN.node[5].xCoor = 50
SN.node[6].xCoor = 60
SN.node[7].xCoor = 70
SN.node[8].xCoor = 80
SN.node[9].xCoor = 90



SN.node[0..9].ResourceManager.initialEnergy = 1000
SN.node[*].Communication.Radio.RadioParametersFile = "../Parameters/Radio/CC2420.txt"

SN.node[*].Communication.Radio.collectTraceInfo = false
SN.node[*].Communication.Radio.TxOutputPower = "-5dBm"
SN.node[*].Communication.MAC.collectTraceInfo = false
SN.node[*].Communication.Routing.collectTraceInfo = true
SN.node[*].Application.collectTraceInfo = false

SN.wirelessChannel.onlyStaticNodes = true
SN.wirelessChannel.sigma = 0
SN.wirelessChannel.bidirectionalSigma = 0


#amount of packets sent
SN.node[*].ApplicationName = "ThroughputTest"
SN.node[9].Application.packet_rate = 300

# Here i define the static routing

SN.node[9].Application.nextRecipient = "8"
SN.node[8].Application.nextRecipient = "7"
SN.node[7].Application.nextRecipient = "6"
SN.node[6].Application.nextRecipient = "5"
SN.node[5].Application.nextRecipient = "4"
SN.node[4].Application.nextRecipient = "3"
SN.node[3].Application.nextRecipient = "2"
SN.node[2].Application.nextRecipient = "1"
SN.node[1].Application.nextRecipient = "0"



SN.node[*].Communication.Radio.collisionModel = 2

SN.node[*].Communication.MACProtocolName = "Basic802154"
SN.node[0].Communication.MAC.isFFD = true
SN.node[0].Communication.MAC.isPANCoordinator = true
SN.node[*].Communication.MAC.phyDataRate = 30
SN.node[*].Communication.MAC.phyBitsPerSymbol = 4
```

These are the results:
./../../bin/CastaliaResults -i 180424-155036.txt -s consumed -n

ResourceManager:Consumed Energy
+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| node=0  | node=1  | node=2 | node=3  | node=4  | node=5 | node=6  | node=7  | node=8  | node=9  |
+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 475.988 | 158.176 | 162.13 | 475.997 | 475.999 | 476    | 475.998 | 475.998 | 475.997 | 475.999 |
+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+

These results are not correct, because Node 0 should be the one with more enery consumption by far due it has to cordinate the network and there  should be an incremental increase of energy consumption from 9 to 1 being 9 the node with less energy consumption.

For what i see in the results that i got from Castalia, seems that the static routing is not working , since node 1 and 2  has less energy consumption because are in range to comunicate with node 0 and the other nodes consume the maximoun amount of energy defined due to the distance with the coordinator.

Comment: You're using a packet rate of 300 packets per second. I imagine there is simply no time for the nodes to sleep and save energy. What happens if you have, for example, a packet rate of 1?

Comment: The only node that is transmitting is node 9 but any node is receiving the transmittion due is trying to comunicate with the coordinator and there is not packet forwarding. It seems a mac issue of the implementation of "Basic802154"

Comment: You are writing "the energy consumption is not accurate" but you seem to mean that the energy consumption is not what you expected. These are two very different things. Please edit your question to make this clear.

Comment: You are right 

done

Answer (score 1):

The results that you get are accurate, they are just not what you expected.

The very first thing I noticed with your ini file was that you are using application-level static routing together with the 802.15.4 MAC. These two will not work together. The 802.15.4 MAC Castalia implementation only allows traffic between the coordinator (node 0 in your case) and the slave nodes. Slave nodes cannot talk directly to each other. So you cannot route packets from node 9 to node 8 for example. The [Castalia User's manual](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/blob/master/Castalia%20-%20User%20Manual.docx) clearly states so in section 4.3.3

Moreover, it seems that your network is not even formed the way you intended (node 0 being the coordinator and node 1-9 the slaves). Your transmission power is too low, and so the beacons from node 0 cannot reach very far. Judging from the energy output, I think it's safe to assume that the beacon does not reach further than node 2. Only nodes 1 and 2 are associated with the coordinator. Once associated, the nodes enter a duty cycle (putting the radio to sleep on and off). This is why you see them consuming less energy. The rest of the nodes are probably having their radios always on trying to listen to a beacon. That's why you see them consume much more energy.

Study the protocols you want to use so you understand them in depth. Read the Castalia manual to understand the specifics of how Castalia implements these protocols. Turn on the trace info of different modules (e.g. MAC, App) to better understand what they are doing under your specific scenario.

Comment: Thanks for answer and your tips.

Do you know if there is any routing protocol that allows static routing with one coordinator and different slaves which forward traffic between them i order to reach the coordinator? Or a way to send random traffic from a node following a specific route to reach another node?

I checked all mac,routing and application protocols and couldn't get any expected results